# Fast compilation for Salesforce

Tags: apex, mavensmate, sublime, compile

I have **Sublime Text 3** with **MavensMate** plugin.

Also have **MavensMate** application setup in the machine.

Whenever I save any `apex` file it goes to the server and gets any errors found. Which is a bit slow.

Sometimes we need to save the file just to get any compilation error.

Getting any compilation issues quicky will accelerate the development process.

Is there any plugin for Sublime Text or any other mechanism which can fast forward the compilation issue finding process?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, you are already using the SFDX tools (see e.g. [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx)) that together with server-side changes have made compilation a bit faster.

There is no 100% client-side solution today. The commonly used IDEs - [VSCode](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-visual-studio-code) and [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/) - both offer a level of syntax checking and auto-completion that help a bit. But ultimately, from time to time, you have to wait the 10 seconds or so for the changed files to be pushed to the server and verified.

(Colleagues who use Illuminated Cloud - that requires an entirely reasonable, small annual fee to be paid - report that it does more for them than the VSCode solution.)